Can we substitute 'so that' for 'such that' in 'cannot be ordered in a strict hierarchy such that if a given manipulation is permitted then'?
Original:


Moreover, the manipulations cannot be ordered in a strict hierarchy such that if a given manipulation is permitted then all others below it in the hierarchy will be permitted too.


Substituted:


Moreover, the manipulations cannot be ordered in a strict hierarchy so that if a given manipulation is permitted then all others below it in the hierarchy will be permitted too.


They seem to have the same meaning as '...in such a strict hierarchy that...'.
But when concerning 'in order that', it seems different.


They never parked the big van in front of the house in order that they wouldn't upset the neighbours.




They never parked the big van in front of the house so that they wouldn't upset the neighbours.


In #2, it is 'ordered in a strict hierarchy' that makes '...if a given manipulation is permitted then all others below it in the hierarchy will be permitted too....' with the positive main clause.
But in #4, it is 'never parked the big van in front of the house' that makes '...they wouldn't upset the neighbours.', with the negative main clause.

I don't think it does mean 'in such a strict hierarchy that...'. I understand it to mean 'in such a way that...'

@Kate Bunting Does #1 and #2 have the same meaning?

As you show in your examples #3 and #4, so that means in order that. I understand such that as meaning in such a way that or with the result that.

@KateBunting, I read such that here as being used essentially in the sense that is common in mathematics. Compare “the set of all points (x, y) such that y = sin x.” Here, such that means with the property that, or maybe  conforming to the condition that.

You write that both (1) and (2) “seem to have the same meaning as '...in such a strict hierarchy that...'.” But in fact neither means “in a hierarchy that is so strict that.”

All these formulations - so that, such that, in order that/to - are used to express the purpose or intentional result of an action but have different connotations. In general, they are interchangeable with the same essential meaning, but the feel will be subtly different.
In your first example (noting that it's quite context dependent) I would prefer "such that", because "such that" tends to refer to the intentional outcome rather than the simple purpose.
Really, this comes down to the mood (technical use of mood) of the purpose phrase. In the first example the mood is indicative. If we define an adjective fooable to mean "a manipulation permissible to a member of a hierarchy is permissible to lesser members in the hierarchy" - then we can rewrite #1 as:

Moreover, the manipulations cannot be ordered in a strict hierarchy [such that] the hierarchy is fooable

Compare this with #4:

They never parked the big van in front of the house so that they would not upset the neighbours.

The purpose in #3 and #4 is a subjunctive purpose while the purpose in #1 and #2 is indicative.
So, the difference is subtle and all the options are broadly interchangeable. But I would tend to prefer such that for indicative uses (statement of fact) and the others for subjunctive uses (statement of possibility).
